# Liferay Custom landing page or last path?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

> User A ----> has "XYZ" role and has "ABC" as home site User B ---->
>   has "PQR" role and has "DEF" as home site

Whenever user A logs in I need to redirect him to site "ABC" rather than default guest site.
Whenever user B logs in I need to redirect him to site "DEF" rather than default guest site.

Through hook I have achieved this

> hook property:
>   login.events.post=com.mytest.portal.events.MyLoginPostAction

And then in MyLoginPostAction I have checked the user role and then redirected him to corresponding site.

Now, say user A has subscribed to the blog on any of the site. He receives an emaial containing link to that Blog.

User A is logged out and then he tries to reach that Blog with direct link. Since user A is not logged in, he is redirected to login page.
On log in he is redirected to site "ABC" rather than going to that Blog. This is due to I am redirecting User to home site.

So how can I achieve this scenarioes i.e when user try to access that Blog page when not logged in then on log in he should go to that blog page and when user just try to log in to portal then he should redirect to home site.

Comment: Interesting! You could have achieved this with default Login mechanism of liferay based on your redirect url, if any page is hit directly otherwise filter it based on user role.

Comment: Override LoginAction.java to plugin environment and debug through code  and add your filter logic in execute method.

Comment: @Parkash Kumar : I am able to redirect user to his home site but this functionality is adding a barrier when user click on link they got in email after subscribing to particular blog.So I am interested to know if there is any way to identify if login request is made just for login and not to view subscriptions og assets like blogs

Comment: You must decide once user has successfully logged in that has he come from another page or default login page.

Comment: How about popping up a fast login dialog in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can get lastpath object in your action class by 
`request.getSession().getAttribute("LAST_PATH")`

And based on path value from lastpath object, you can determine where to redirect.

Comment: This lastpath attribute in LoginPostAction's hook gives only path where your login portlet is and not the path from where request originated.
For ex. If you logged out and then try to access say test page of say Test site so it will redirect you to login page.Now if you have your login portlet on home page of guest site then this last path in LoginPostAction would be /guest/home and not /test/test which I require so that I can identify that this is not the default login where I simply have to forward user to his home site.

Answer (score 0):

By necessary login by direct link, Liferay set the forward path as url parameter. May be you can read the `redirect` parameter from request and decide to forward to specific page or not.

Comment: Yup mark I am following this approach only. Now the logic is working for me on my local environment. But when I test this against auto login feature of liferay, it is not forwarding it to default landing page which I set through hook.

Comment: You use AutoLogin Feature? Do you have develope one?

Comment: Yes I am using custom AutoLogin